# Simple implementation of SHA-3 Keccak hashing to the wrong output in C#?

Tags: c#, hash, sha-3, keccak

I am trying to get the HashLib library @ https://hashlib.codeplex.com/ working for the new SHA-3 Keccak algorithm. I've written a simple Console application that supposedly has to output the correct hash code, but it doesn't!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using HashLib;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                string passPhrase = "";
                IHash hash = HashFactory.Crypto.SHA3.CreateKeccak512();
                HashResult r = hash.ComputeString(passPhrase, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            
                Console.WriteLine(r.ToString().ToLower().Replace("-",""));
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", hash.BlockSize, hash.HashSize, hash.Name);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The application builds and runs ok, but the output is very wrong. When I use other people 's implementations of the Keccak algorithm, I get different results and it doesn't match for example this wiki post either. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3 So something is obviously wrong.

When I leave the text empty, as per example, I get the following: "df987cfd23fbc92e7e87faaca300ec3f etc. etc." while the wiki and other tools say I should get

"0eab42de4c3ceb9235fc91acffe746b29c29a8c366b7c60e4e67c466f36a4304c00fa9caf9d87976ba469bcbe06713b435f091ef2769fb160cdab33d3670680e"

,which is something entirely different. I also tried it with non-empty strings of course.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Looks like one of the implementation or your check value is wrong. It's possible they changed the IV when they named it SHA-3 to make it hash differently from Keccak.

Comment: looks like the values that you are getting were for SHA-3 -256 as well I would personally update the HashLib and get the latest version

Comment: David, I am sorry to say the latest code (changeset 78295) does not solve the problem. When I use the following code IHash hash = HashFactory.Crypto.SHA3.CreateKeccak512(); HashResult res = hash.ComputeString("", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII); string dd = res.ToString(); in my VS 2012 IDE, i am getting a result as DF987CFD-23FBC92E-7E87FAAC-A300EC3F-AA1DBADC-678E8EE9-4A830968-F22D9209-64AB402D-C5D0F7B2-0C9644BE-08056555-C789D295-8BDA3DF9-8C94BACC-EA25D3C1 which is same as the problem specified I am not sure whether the changes are inplace When I used the test vector which was taken from the file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your version of HashLib is too old. If you look at the [recent changes](https://hashlib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/diff/file/view/77942?fileId=1104881) you can see the test vector changed from the one you got to the one you should get. (The algorithm changed as well, of course.)

Comment: Could you please clarify, when did the algorithm change?