# Difference between Hashlib and System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm

Tags: c#, hashlib, hashalgorithm

I am trying to understand how hashing algorithms works, specially SHA3-512. To see how it works I searched for codes in Google and came across with [Hashlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061299/simple-implementation-of-sha-3-keccak-hashing-to-the-wrong-output-in-c/19081822#19081822). The code doesn't work as I don't have the Hashlib library (not sure what it should be called). How can I get that and is it the only way to apply SHA3-512 in C#?

Some basic things that I want to know,

1. What is `Hashlib`?
2. Is it a  Library?
3. Is the output result/work process/function of `Hashlib` and `System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm` same? If not, then what is the difference between them?

**Edit:** Sorry for removing few questions from the middle. As I feel they don't need to be shown here anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note:** Updated 2017.

#### Hashlib

Hashlib is a library of hash implementations:

https://hashlib.codeplex.com/

It includes implementations of quite a few cryptographic and non-cryptographic hashes - both ones that are already supported by the .NET framework (in `System.Security.Cryptography`) and ones that aren't. You'll need it - or another external implementation - to support SHA-3.

Note, however, that Hashlib doesn't actually include SHA-3 in its final form - but rather, the way it looked before some adjustments were made to it. That means, its output will not be what you'd expect from SHA-3.

HashLib uses a different architecture than .NET's `HashAlgorithm` for its hash algorithms - the output is the same (for the same algorithm, e.g. `SHA256`), the usage isn't. But it has a wrapper/adapter that can make the workflow the same as for `HashAlgorithm`, for example:

```
IHash hash = HashFactory.Crypto.SHA3.CreateKeccak512();
HashAlgorithm hashAlgo = HashFactory.Wrappers.HashToHashAlgorithm(hash);
// Now hashAlgo can be used the same as any .NET HashAlgorithm, e.g.:

// Create byte input from string encoded as UTF-8
byte[] input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello Keccak!");

byte[] output = hashAlgo.ComputeHash(bytes);
```

But again, be aware that `Keccak512` is not the same as SHA-3 - it won't give the same hash as an actual 512 bit SHA-3 implementation.

Actual implementations of the final SHA-3 in C# are still (2017) few and far between - the difference to Keccak as implemented in Hashlib is extremely minor, although it has major impact on the output, as would be the case for a hash algorithm - since Wikipedia no longer provides an example of the difference, here's one:

```
Keccak-512('abc') =
Keccak[1024]('abc', 512) =
    18 58 7d c2 ea 10 6b 9a 15 63 e3 2b 33 12 42 1c
    a1 64 c7 f1 f0 7b c9 22 a9 c8 3d 77 ce a3 a1 e5
    d0 c6 99 10 73 90 25 37 2d c1 4a c9 64 26 29 37
    95 40 c1 7e 2a 65 b1 9d 77 aa 51 1a 9d 00 bb 96

SHA3-512('abc') =
Keccak[1024]('abc' || 01, 512) =
    b7 51 85 0b 1a 57 16 8a 56 93 cd 92 4b 6b 09 6e
    08 f6 21 82 74 44 f7 0d 88 4f 5d 02 40 d2 71 2e
    10 e1 16 e9 19 2a f3 c9 1a 7e c5 76 47 e3 93 40
    57 34 0b 4c f4 08 d5 a5 65 92 f8 27 4e ec 53 f0
```

`Keccak[c](M || s, d)` means "Keccak with *capacity* `c`, *message* `M`, *suffix bits* `s`, and *output size* `d`."

This (from the Wikipedia article) is the only difference between "standard" Keccak (and Hashlib's implementation) and SHA-3 as it looks in the current spec:

> For SHA3-n, an additional two bits 01 are appended to the message before padding.

Implementing it (by e.g. patching the Hashlib code) isn't trivial, though, without knowing how Hashlib works.

#### So, should you use SHA-3?

It depends on what you want it for - it's no good if you want compatibility with the finalized SHA-3 standard.

The whole Keccak family, independent of SHA-3, is a standard in itself - but NIST's tweaks for SHA-3 are still Keccak - just a specific subset of it (much like AES is a subset of Rijndael). When SHA-3 eventually shows up in - for example - the .NET framework itself, it will likely just be SHA-3 with the parameters NIST picked, rather than a generic Keccak with tweakable parameters.

#### SHA-512 (answer to a part of the question that has now been removed)

SHA-512 is **SHA-2** 512 bit - *not* the same as SHA-3 512. That said, to use it, you simply import `System.Security.Cryptography` - `using` in this case imports the *namespace* - making the classes inside the namespace available to your code.

After that, the workflow is the same as any other `HashAlgorithm`.

#### So, should I use SHA-2 or SHA-3 for hashing passwords?

**Neither of them**. Or at least neither on their own. And while a salt improves matters, that's not optimal security either. See [How to securely hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/), specifically starting from:

> A basic hash function, even if secure *as a hash function*, is not appropriate for password hashing

Comment: Thanks for your answer. you mention,  "or another external implementation - to support SHA-3." exactly what is this another external implementation? and I just downloaded the hashlib2.1 but it has errors.

Comment: " its output will not be what you'd expect from SHA-3." ---if this is the case then I should not use or try to use hashlib at all.

Comment: Thanks man! now  all my confusion is gone. I am clear about SHA3-512 and Keccak-512. I'm doing a project on block cipher and wish to hash the password. Since SHA3-512 is still a draft so I should go with SHA2-512.

Comment: The SHA3-n, are they all draft?

Comment: One last thing (just to add some new doubts ;-) ) - about using SHA-3, SHA-2, or any hash algorithm for the purpose of hashing passwords, do have a look at this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/ (changed link to a more informative question/answer)

Answer (score 3):

> What is [Hashlib](http://hashlib.codeplex.com/)?

Basically it's a library implementing many hashing algorithms.

> Is it a Library?

Yes

> Is the output result/work process/function of Hashlib and
>   System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm same? If not, then what is
>   the difference between them?

Yes.

Hashlib provides the `HashLib.HashFactory.Wrappers` which can be used to convert the implementation provided by hashlib to `System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm`

It can be used this way.

```
IHash hash = HashFactory.Crypto.CreateSHA256();
System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm algorith = HashLib.HashFactory.Wrappers.HashToHashAlgorithm(hash);
```

Comment: So, Basically 'Hashlib' gives its output to 'System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm'. Whats the benefit of doing this? I can easily use 'SHA512Managed()' class instead. Don't you agree?

Comment: HashLib doesn't "give its output" to anything. The code Justin (and I) provide simply lets you use HashLib algorithms with the same interface (as in methods and properties) as `HashAlgorithm`. The benefit of using HashLib is getting support for hash algorithms that *aren't* implemented in .NET itself. Plus, support on platforms with a reduced .NET framework, because HashLib also has its own implementations of all algorithms the full .NET framework provides. Yes, you can use `SHA512Managed` (or `SHA512`) if that's what you need - and it's supported on your target. But note that it's not SHA-3.