# How can i get sha3-512 hash in C#?

Tags: c#, hash, sha, hashlib, sha-3

exaple, string "test" in https://md5calc.com/hash/sha3-512/test gives me "9ece086e9bac491fac5c1d1046ca11d737b92a2b2ebd93f005d7b710110c0a678288166e7fbe796883a4f2e9b3ca9f484f521d0ce464345cc1aec96779149c14"

but

```
using HashLib; // from https://www.nuget.org/packages/HashLib
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sha3512 = HashFactory.Crypto.SHA3.CreateKeccak512();
        var tempHash = sha3512.ComputeString("test");
        Console.WriteLine(tempHash.ToString().ToLower().Replace("-", ""));
    }
}
```

returns
"3abff7b1f2042ac3861bd4c0b40efaa8a695909bfb31753fc7b1bd69778de1225a627c8f07cf4814cc05435ada2a1ffee3f4513a8867154274787624f24e551b"

i need to get first string, not that hashlib provides.

Comment: Well, which one is wrong? Are you sure this line is not you problem `Console.WriteLine(tempHash.ToString().ToLower().Replace("-", ""));`?

Comment: @Jodrell the 9ece from the website is correct

Comment: is the site doing utf8? im guessing the .net one is doing something different.

Comment: What is `HashFactory`?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098253/difference-between-hashlib-and-system-security-cryptography-hashalgorithm

Comment: Be aware that Keccak512 is not the same as SHA-3 - it won't give the same hash as an actual 512 bit SHA-3 implementation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [BouncyCastle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/). It has an SHA3 implementation.

```
var hashAlgorithm = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha3Digest(512);

// Choose correct encoding based on your usecase
byte[] input = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test");

hashAlgorithm.BlockUpdate(input, 0, input.Length);

byte[] result = new byte[64]; // 512 / 8 = 64
hashAlgorithm.DoFinal(result, 0);

string hashString = BitConverter.ToString(result);
hashString = hashString.Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();

Console.WriteLine(hashString);
```

Output is

> 9ece086e9bac491fac5c1d1046ca11d737b92a2b2ebd93f005d7b710110c0a678288166e7fbe796883a4f2e9b3ca9f484f521d0ce464345cc1aec96779149c14