# SHA3 encryption in .Net 4.0 Framework

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, sha-3

Is there a way to encrypt a string using SHA3 in C# .Net 4.0 framework. SHA3.Net supports from .Net 4.5 onwards.

Comment: For the record, SHA stands for Secure Hashing Algorithm. It's for hashing, which is one-way, rather than encrypting, which is two-way, i.e. encryption/decryption.

Comment: SHA3.NET is [open source](https://github.com/dariogriffo/sha3.net), you could download it and try if it compiles with .NET 4.

Comment: According to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57857330/how-can-i-get-sha3-512-hash-in-c), BouncyCastle has a SHA3 implementation. I'm not 100% sure that the latest version supports .NET Framework 4 but it looks like it does.